# Javascript Class + Properties not sticking to their values

Tags: javascript, oop, properties

I'm attempting to make a class in javascript. I create it with the JSON type object thing.

Doing this:

```
Foo = {
   PubId: '',

   Init:function( oCallback )
   {
         this.sendCommand( 'INIT', {}, oCallback );
   },

    sendCommand : function( sCommand, aParams, oCallback )
    {

        setTimeout( oCallback, 1000, '{"response":"INIT","time":1287982024,"pubid":"4cc50bc47c7b3"}' );

        return true;
    },
    onData : function( sData )
    {
        var aRes = JSON.parse( sData );

        this.PubId = aRes.pubid;
        alert( this.PubId );
        return this.PubId;
    },
    umtest:function(){ alert( this.PubId ); }
}
```

I then also do this after including the script:

```
Foo.Init( Foo.onData );
```

The problem is that the this.PubId is updated inside the onData method, but outside of it, the pubid is empty.

I am pretty new at javascript classes, so I'm not sure what needs to be done so I was hoping someone could help meh out. :)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you've got two problems here. The **first** problem is not understanding how `this` works in Javascript. When `Foo.onData` is called via `setTimeout( oCallback, ...)` the `this` will reference to the global object not `Foo`.

In order to call it with `Foo` as `this` you should change your code:

```
sendCommand: function (sCommand, aParams, oCallback) {
    var that = this;           // save this reference
    setTimeout(function () {
        oCallback.call( that,  // call the function with it
               '{"response":"INIT","time":1287982024,"pubid":"4cc50bc47c7b3"}' );
    }, 1000);
    return true;
},
```

In order to test what's changed place this code to `onData`:

```
// is `this` really Foo or the global object?
alert(this === Foo);    // should be true
alert(this === window); // should be false
```

In the updated version `this` will correctly reference `Foo` as it's object of invocation.

The **second** problem you might be facing with is that your function called with `setTimeout` will only be executed after `1000 ms = 1s`, so if you're simply checking `alert(Foo.PubId)` outside of `Foo` you will get an empty string (because the callback hasn't been called yet).

In order to test if `Foo.PubId` is indeed changed:

```
// execute the check after 2s so as to
// make sure the callback has been called
setTimeout( function () {
  alert(Foo.PubId);
}, 2000);
```

You can check the full test case [here](http://jsbin.com/ehimi3/).

Comment: Thanks for the help! And same goes for everyone else. lol wish I could up vote all of you but I guess I must be a user of the site a bit longer before I can do that. Anyway, thanks for the solution galambalazs. I had no idea Javascript passed the function instead of the method. Lame! Anywho, on with the code. (That jsbin site is wicked cool too!)

Answer (score 1):

When a method belonging to an object is called using dot notation, its context (where `this` points to) is the object that it's connected to.  For example:

```
// Context: `this` is `myObj`
myObj.myMethod();
```

However, when you store a reference to that function in a different variable, it loses that contextual relationship and the context becomes the global object:

```
// Context: `this` is the global object - `window` in a web browser
var myMethod = myObj.myMethod;
myMethod();
```

When executing a method, you can use its `call` or `apply` method to specify the context you would like it to execute in:

```
// Context: `this` is `myObj`
var myMethod = myObj.myMethod;
myMethod.call(myObj);
```

In your particular example, I would consider using a new method introduced in newer versions of JavaScript named `bind`.  `bind` is supported by IE9, Firefox 4 and newer versions of Google Chrome and Safari, and it allows you to "lock" a function to a particular context.  You can implement most of its functionality in browsers that don't support it using the following code (taken from the MDC documentation for [*Function.prototype.bind*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)):

```
// PARTIAL WORKAROUND for Function.prototype.bind  
if (!Function.prototype.bind)  
    Function.prototype.bind = function(context /*, arg1, arg2... */) {  
        'use strict';  
        if (typeof this !== 'function') throw new TypeError();  
        var _slice = Array.prototype.slice,  
            _concat = Array.prototype.concat,  
            _arguments = _slice.call(arguments, 1),  
            _this = this,  
            _function = function() {  
                return _this.apply(this instanceof _dummy ? this : context,  
                    _concat.call(_arguments, _slice.call(arguments, 0)));  
            },  
            _dummy = function() {};  
        _dummy.prototype = _this.prototype;  
        _function.prototype = new _dummy();  
        return _function;  
};
```

Using it in your code is very simple:

```
Foo.Init( Foo.onData.bind(Foo) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I would rather not rely on a workaround however to get it to work with older browsers. :/

Comment: @dab: it's not really a "workaround", it's just a less functional implementation. That missing functionality isn't required here. For what you need to do, *bind()* would have been the better solution because you're very much in control of the context from the point of reference (where you call the Init method).  And for newer browsers, the result would have been even faster because there's a native solution.

Answer (score 0):

The onData is executed separat from the class.

You have to call like this

```
Foo.Init(function(d) { Foo.onData(d);} );
```

for this to work as excpected.

Comment: this is an *anonymous function*, not a *closure*.

Answer (score 0):

It is a scope problem. When you pass `Foo.onData` to your `init` function, it "looses" the connection to the class. Functions are first class objects, so they can exist by themselves. You could do the following:

```
Foo = {
   PubId: '',

   Init:function(oCallback, scope)
   {
         this.sendCommand('INIT', {}, oCallback, scope);
   },

    sendCommand : function(sCommand, aParams, oCallback, scope)
    {
        var cb = oCallback;
        if(scope) {
            cb = function(data) {
               oCallback.call(scope, data); 
            };
        }

        setTimeout( cb, 1000, '{"response":"INIT","time":1287982024,"pubid":"4cc50bc47c7b3"}' );

        return true;
    }
    //...
}
```

and then call it with

```
Foo.Init(Foo.onData, Foo);
```

The first parameter that is passed to [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) will become `this` inside the method.